# Database multiple state field vs 1 state field

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing database for an application which have 2 components: Web and Core backend.

My problem is Web and Core have different state of a same entity

- Web (2 states): `SHOW`/`HIDE`
- Core backend (many other states): START/queueing/processing/foo/bar/DONE

After many states in core backend, Web can choose show or hide that entity on front end. I mean `DONE` state of backend can be `SHOW`/`HIDE` in Web.

Should I separate these states into 2 fields in DB or merge them into 1 field?

And what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Is it anyone want to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a map table from your various back-end states into the sub-states (web states).

If those sub-states are purely for the web application then I'd just do it as front-end logic.  If the mapping is an actual "business thing" and has actual meaning that affects process, is understood outside of tech or requires to be reported upon then do it in the database.

If it's somewhere in between then put it in your middle/business layer!